# Android aapt crash when including any kind of resources

Tags: android, crash, coredump, aapt

I'm having some troubles packing resources into an apk using `aapt`. Everything works fine when having no `@drawable/[...]` or `@styles/[...]` directions in my `AndroidManifest.xml`. But as soon as i add for example `android:icon="@drawable/icon"` aapt crashes *after parsing my icon file (so compressing the image and stuff seems to work).

The command i'm using is:

`aapt package -v -f -M AndroidManifest.xml -S res -I android.jar -F test.apk`

It fails when using `-S res` and adding @-directions in the manifest. Otherwise it succeeds.

**Output log:**

```
[...]
applyFileOverlay for menu
applyFileOverlay for mipmap
Processing image: res/drawable/icon.png
Processing image: res/drawable-ldpi/icon.png
Processing image: res/drawable-xhdpi/icon.png
    (processed image res/drawable-ldpi/icon.png: 82% size of source)
    (processed image res/drawable-xhdpi/icon.png: 95% size of source)
    (processed image res/drawable/icon.png: 60% size of source)
    (new resource id icon from drawable/icon.png #generated)
    (new resource id icon from ldpi-v4/drawable/icon.png #generated)
    (new resource id icon from xhdpi-v4/drawable/icon.png #generated)
Aborted (dump written)
```

The exit code is 134, couldn't find anything about it

Thanks

## Edit

All the resources are used in an Android Studio project. As that one compiles without any issues i assume the resources are valid

(seems to be a problem with aapt or xml parsing, i think gradle replaces aapt's tasks in Android Studio)

Also, since it could also be a system specific issue, here are my specs:

- Ubuntu 16.04.4 64bit
- AMD Processor (6 cores)
- Locale: German
- Terminal used for testing: `gnome-terminal`

## Edit - Contents of AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.company.app"> <!-- Of cause different but no special chars -->
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon" <!-- With this line, crashes -->
        android:label="Title" <!-- Again different title but only english letters -->
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:testOnly="false">
        <activity android:name="immerse.MAct">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

## Update

Tried again without `@drawable/icon` but with resources. Still crashing.

So it doesn't seem to be an xml issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved! For me the problem has solved now. My solution was to install a newer version of aapt and all it's dependencies from debian sid.

The command now runs without an error!

I downloaded all required files from [here](https://debian.pkgs.org) and [here](https://packages.debian.org/stretch) starting with package `aapt` of course, dpkg will tell you dependencies (some can be installed via `apt`)

Thanks to these sites!

Answer (score 2):

Try to adjust your images size(make them lower) it seem they are in very large resolution and they take much more memory.

Comment: Thanks! Well, it also crashed with the default icon generated by android studio, as well as with a 1x1px png icon, but i will try it out

Comment: okay, i checked all the resources. They are all on the recommended resolution (max is xhdpi with 144x144) and the largest file is ~1.5kb. I don't think that's the problem but thanks for your answer!

Comment: can you write here the code that you are writting in manifest file?

Comment: ok .try to create new image assets and put there mipmap instead of drawable . if you dont know how to do this. jusk ask google how to chang app icon android.

Comment: Fails with mipmaps as well sadly. Tried the ones from google services core. These should be valid